# Homestead private network suddenly not accessible

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've been using homestead 5.2 for local development for about half a year, but now I can't access it via 192.168.10.10 anymore and I can't figure out why.

1. virtual box can successfully booted and nginx service is listening.
2. ping 192.168.10.10 form my mac failed.
3. run ifconfig from my mac does't shows 192.168.10.10.
4. change ip from 192.168.10.10 to 192.168.10.20, still no luck.
5. vm port forward works
6. I tried bring up another centos vm with private network and it's not accessable too.

vagrant up output:

```
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
    homestead-7: Adapter 3: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 6001 (guest) => 60010 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

ifconfig on mac:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
vboxnet1: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01
        inet 192.168.10.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
vboxnet2: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02
```

ifconfig on homestead:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b2:79:ef
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb2:79ef/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1226 (1.2 KB)
```

I don't want to reinstall my homestead to make it work again.

now what information should I provide and what to check next?

Comment: I should add another new homestead to check if it's caused by vagrant config. but I'm living in China with super slow network connection when init a new box.

Comment: What does ifconfig from your mac show? Are you in the same subnetwork with the vm?

Comment: [Solved] Same Issue again. It turns out that vboxnet0 and vboxnet2 has not `UP`(check it in ifconfig flags). So I run `sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up` and `sudo ifconfig vboxnet2 up` and then back to normal.